# Best way to print variables depending on a given input order, like ABC or CAB in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to learn C#, so I'm doing assignments on [open.kattis.com](https://open.kattis.com/problems/abc).
I have three variables called A, B and C and have to print them in a given order.
A is the smallest variable, B is the middle variable and C is the largest variable.

I give the variables 1, 2, 5 and the order ABC, so the output print is 1 2 5
I give the variables 1, 10, 22 and the order CAB, so the output is 22 1 10

My question however is to improve my code. Right now I'm checking the input-order in a switch-case and was wondering if there is a better way.

My submission can be seen here:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        string order = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] inputArray = {0, 0, 0};
        int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            inputArray[i] = Int32.Parse(input[i]);
        }
        A = inputArray.Min();
        C = inputArray.Max();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inputArray[i] != A && inputArray[i] != C)
            {
                B = inputArray[i];
            }
        }

        switch (order)
        {
            case "ABC":
                Console.WriteLine($"{A} {B} {C}");
                break;
            case "ACB":
                Console.WriteLine($"{A} {C} {B}");
                break;
            case "BAC":
                Console.WriteLine($"{B} {A} {C}");
                break;
            case "BCA":
                Console.WriteLine($"{B} {C} {A}");
                break;
            case "CBA":
                Console.WriteLine($"{C} {B} {A}");
                break;
            case "CAB":
                Console.WriteLine($"{C} {A} {B}");
                break;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change the string in `order` variable to just have curly braces, enclosing each character, then you can avoid the entire block of switch..case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One answer is super advanced and the other answer fails for any unsorted input, so here's my shot at helping you out.*

You can generalise, for any number of inputs, two important parts of your task:

- Getting min, max, middle (or min, ..., max for >3 items): this can be done by sorting the collection.
- Translating order expressed as letters to the indexes of the elements in the now sorted array.

### Min, Middle, Max

```
var a = new[] {22, 10, 1};
Array.Sort(a);

var min = a[0];
var middle = a[1];
var max = a[2];

Console.WriteLine($"{min}, {middle}, {max}");
```

This prints

```
1, 10, 21
```

### From CAB to 2,0,1 (indexes)

Characters (~letters) in C# have number values and we can exploit that.

```
char c1 = 'A';
char c2 = 'B';

Console.WriteLine((byte)c1);
Console.WriteLine((byte)c2);
Console.WriteLine(c1 - 'A');
Console.WriteLine(c2 - 'A');
```

This prints

```
65
66
0
1
```

Knowing this let's try to translate "CAB":

```
string order = "CAB";

foreach(char c in order)
{
    int index = c - 'A';
    Console.WriteLine($"Character '{c}' is index: {index}");
}
```

This prints:

```
Character 'C' is index: 2
Character 'A' is index: 0
Character 'B' is index: 1
```

## Solution

Equipped with these two transformations you should be able to generalise your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

Let's *generalize* the solution. So you have data array:

```
int[] inputArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3}
```

and `order`:

```
string order = "BAC";
```

Now we can *loop* over `order` and output corresponding array's item:

```
for (char letter in order)
  Console.Write($"{inputArray[letter - 'A']} ");
```

Here we convert `letter`s from `order` (`B`, `A`, `C`) into indexes (`1`, `0`, `2`)

Please note, that we can well use array, say, of 2 or 4 items providing that we have corresponding `order`

**Code:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  string[] input = Console
    .ReadLine()
    .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  int[] inputArray = new int[input.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    inputArray[i] = int.Parse(input[i]);

  Array.Sort(inputArray);

  string order = Console.ReadLine();

  for (char letter in order)
    Console.Write($"{inputArray[letter - 'A']} ");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for unsorted input array.

Comment: @tymtam: thank you! My bad. I haven't paid attention that values should be sorted before printing out.

Answer (score 2):

Your app:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).OrderBy(x=> x).ToArray();
        var order = Console.ReadLine().Select(x=> x-'A');

        var output = string.Join(" ", order.Select(x => input[x]));
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Work for custom number of inputs.